# What happens if __getitem__ return None to dataloader in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, pytorch-dataloader

What happens if `__getitem__` return None to dataloader in Pytorch?

In my gussing, the batch size will be reduced and training will continue?

Comment: Do you mean for some index or for every index?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are wrong. The dataset's length nor the batch size will be reduced automatically as you are expecting it to. Also your code is most likely to crash.

> batch size will be reduced

The size of your instance is provided by `__len__` and needs to be available after `__init__` has been run. So unless `__len__` infers its length by querying `__getitem__` and checking if the returned object is `None`, then the size of your dataset will naturally contain those indices for which the item is `None`. That being said, even if the dataset sometimes returns `None`, this is not a problem... unless you use a dataloader on top of that.

> training will continue

If you are wrapping your dataset with a dataloader, then a collate function is at play. This function allows to construct batches by querying the dataset's `__getitem__` function. In your scenario, since some of the indices might return `None`, then it will return an error of the form:

```
default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>
```